# gem dependency hell for the newbie with bad karma

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a ruby newbie.  I want to know about gem dependencies in general, but my example is rspec-rails.  I run `gem dependency rspec-rails -r` I get a list of dependencies.  I think, ok this is pretty cool.  I look at the first dependency in the list for `rspec-rails`, it's `ZenTest`.  Next, I wonder if `ZenTest` has any unlisted dependencies. I would hope it doesn't.  I go `gem dependency ZenTest -r`. It lists three unique dependencies.  Wow this sucks.  what good is this command if it's not recursive.  So my question is, how do people avoid this hell?

Comment: This is not a forum. Please, read the FAQ to see why it would be better to post your question without all the added commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). It handles recursive gem dependencies quite nicely.